Could a black hole be shaped like a torus?
I am familiar with the Kerr metric, which states that a black hole can spin. I also know that, due to the spin, the singularity is ring shaped. I wonder, if enough spin is given to the black hole, that it could have a toroidal shape. I also wonder what properties the 'hole' in the torus has. If it isn't a torus, then what shape is it?

Not really. See this related question on our sister site: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730094/123208

I'm a little confused by your question. I thought "ring-shaped" and "toroidal-shaped" were basically the same shape... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroid

The singularity is like the circumference of a circle, infinitely thin, but curved into a circle
